# jQuery Confirm Dialog - Conflicting Classes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, function

I'm trying to get a confirm dialog to work, but I already have a class attribute in my URL:

```
<a href="deleteMe.php?key=<?php echo $key; ?> class="load-external" data-target="#right_section">Delete Me</a>
```

I found this sample below, and when I use Class "confirmation" it works in my link above, but I need to use "load-external" as it is loading the content (deleteMe.php) back into the same DIV, not into an entirely new page.

```
<a href="deleteMe.php?key=22" class="confirmation">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.confirmation').on('click', function () {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete this record?');
});
</script>
```

Is there any way to do this inline, or any other way so it does not conflict with the class="load-external" I must have in my href link ??

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use `.load-external` instead of `.confirmation`?

Comment: @ohgodwhy Maybe the OP does not want a confirmation on *all* the `load-external` links but only on those classed as `confirmation`?

Comment: correct, I only need them on links defined with confirmation .... thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply write:

```
<a href="deleteMe.php?key=<?php echo $key; ?>" 
 class="confirmation load-external" 
 data-target="#right_section">Delete Me</a>
```

You can assign as many classes as you like within the `class` attribute string. Separate them with a blank.

Comment: well call me an idiot ! :) I did not know that I could use multiple classes. Works like a charm. Thanks everyone for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

You can have many classes as you want. Example:

```
<a href="deleteMe.php?key=22" class="confirmation load-external">Link</a>
```

And also you can select many elements as you want, so can be:

```
$('.confirmation, .load-external').on('click', function () {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete this record?');
});
```